After Compilation I got the Error on VScode
Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe build active file

Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001\>nul && C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\\Users\\mohmm\\Downloads\\Programs\\my.cpp -o C:\\Users\\mohmm\\Downloads\\Programs\\my.exe
C:\\Users\\mohmm\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccXth9vd.o: In function `main': C:/Users/mohmm/Downloads/Programs/my.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::cout'
C:/Users/mohmm/Downloads/Programs/my.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)' C:/Users/mohmm/Downloads/Programs/my.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream\<char, std::char_traits\<char\> \>& std::endl\<char, std::char_traits\<char\> \>(std::basic_ostream\<char, std::char_traits\<char\> \>&)'
C:/Users/mohmm/Downloads/Programs/my.cpp:5: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))' C:\Users\mohmm\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXth9vd.o: In function `\_tcf_0':
c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' C:\Users\mohmm\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXth9vd.o: In function `\_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to \`std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).

* The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
* Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I have Installed MinGW Compiler and Added to System Path.I am Expecting the Program to work correctly

Show your code too. Does it include . If not reinstall and follow the steps exactly (and make sure no paths to include folders are left in PATH after uninstall). But since you are on windows, try using "visual studio commmunity edition" (visual studio code is far less user friendly to get started)

replace gcc.exe with g++.exe in the build command or action

#include 
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "Hello World" << endl;
return 0;
}
This is My code

Also, mingw 6.3.0 is a really old version and shows that you didn't follow the official guide to install VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
